# Can Shaka packager SDK read input directly from a memory buffer?

Tags: video, video-streaming, shaka

I'm writing a media processing application using Shaka packager SDK (not the default packager program), basically I'm wrapping up the packager (Shaka::Packager packager;) inside a wrapper application which I wrote.

I know Shaka::Packager can read inputs from local files, UDP streams or pipes, etc. Now, I have a need to have Shaka::packager reading media inputs from a memory buffer which is passed in from the wrapper application (so, the wrapper app will load media data from some file to the memory buffer). I wonder if this is possible. Thanks!

Comment: Memory file (https://github.com/google/shaka-packager/blob/master/packager/file/memory_file.cc) seems to serve my need. However, memory file is not recommended for larger files.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more specific about your input requirements?  Media pipelines like Shaka are stream oriented, so think "look at data once, perform some action, drop".

Looking through the Shaka MemoryFile we can see the backing store is a std::vector so all the data is held in memory for the duration of the pipeline.  Media files can get quite big, I'm working with Tears of Steel 4K at the moment: 7GB for 12 minutes of content.

I see that Shaka provides [CallbackFile](https://google.github.io/shaka-packager/docs/dd/d40/classshaka_1_1CallbackFile.html) interface.  This looks like a good hook subclass to inject your memory buffers.

Comment: MemoryFile works just fine for me. On the input side, I write the media file data to a memory file, and I configure the memory file url (e.g. memory://test.mp4) as the input to the Shaka packager pipeline. Then I start the pipeline and it will read the media data stored in the memory file and start media processing. 

In my use case, Shaka doesn’t need to process a big hours long video file, it only needs to process a sequence of media chunks of several seconds (e.g. hls or dash segments). I haven’t seen any issue so far by using memory file.